# Правильный смысл слова в предложении

Tags: употребление-слов

Смысл следующего предложения в том, что "полигоны заменили свалки".

> В двадцатом веке неорганизованные
> неконтролируемые свалки сменили
> полигонами/полигоны, основанные на
> принципе полной земляной засыпки
> отходов.

Как правильно писать слово *полигон*, чтобы смысл предложения был правильным?

Comment: @RelientK, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Можно так: В двадцатом веке неорганизованные неконтролируемые свалки ЗАменились полигонами, основанными на принципе полной земляной засыпки отходов.

Или: В двадцатом веке на смену неорганизованным неконтролируемым свалкам  пришли полигоны, основанные на принципе полной земляной засыпки отходов.

Или: В двадцатом веке неорганизованные неконтролируемые свалки заменили полигоны, основанные на принципе полной земляной засыпки отходов.

Comment: В последнем варианте смысл предложения тоже кажется неправильным

Comment: Просто я думала, что необходимо оставить исходный вид, а я все заменила. Нужно было сразу объяснить,  с чем связан вопрос

Comment: вас понял.

Answer (score 1):

"Полигоны заменили свалки" - выражение, которое само по себе можно трактовать в противоположных смыслах. Кроме того, в нём имеет место некоторое "одушевление", приписывание активной роли одной из двух сущностей. Такой стиль не очень подходит к столь прозаической теме, поэтому прагматичнее выразиться так: "свалки были заменены полигонами". И смысл будет однозначно понят.

Comment: спор с преподаватьлем вышел из-за того, что предложение выглядело следующим образом. В XX веке неорганизованные неконтролируемые свалки сменили полигоны, основанные на полной земляной засыпке отходов. 
Судя по этому предложению смысл таков, что полигоны были заменены свалками, не так ли? хотя в лекции говориться об обратном

Comment: Из этого предложения нельзя чисто грамматически определить, что было раньше, свалки или полигоны, лучше стало или хуже - и это несмотря на то, что обозначено устройство полигонов.

Comment: вырвано из контекста, поэтому не ясно

Answer (score 0):

В двадцатом веке неорганизованные неконтролируемые свалки сменили полигонами/полигоны, основанные на принципе полной земляной засыпки отходов.

Правильно: сменили полигоны или заменили полигонами.